# How to make a turtle go one step at a time to another turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to write a program which simulates drones picking up packets and delivering them to certain platforms. Once the packets have been delivered, they die. Right now, if a "single step" is performed, the drones move immediately from a packet location to a platform and again to a packet location. However, I'd like the drones to move in actual steps, such that I can include proper waiting times of packets and get a better view of how long it takes to deliver one package.

I have tried to implement "fd 1" in multiple locations (for example immediately in the "to go" function, but also separately in "to fly" or both in "to fly-empty" and "fly-loaded". If I implement the "fd 1" in any of these locations, the drones still jump in (for me seeming to be) random jump sizes and the system stops functioning, as it does not actually pick up any packages. It would be great if someone could help me with this!! Thanks in advance.

```
enter code here
breed [platforms platform]
breed [packets   packet  ]
breed [drones    drone   ]

drones-own  [charge
         mypacket
         status
         consumption
         target
         dropoff
         capacity
         transportedpackets
]

packets-own [destination
         waitingtime
         pickups
         mydrone
         lastdrone
         ]

globals [delivered
     faults
     nrdrones
     deliverydrones
     colorize
     pickedup
     destinationlist
     dronewithpackets]

to setup
  ca
  clear-all-plots
  setup-globals
  setup-platforms
  setup-drones
  setup-packets
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-globals
  set delivered 0
  set faults    0
  set deliverydrones (list)
  set destinationlist(list)
  set colorize       color?
end

to setup-platforms
  create-platforms 1 [setxy -15 6  set color green set shape "circle" set label "Platform 0"]
  create-platforms 1 [setxy -2 10  set color green set shape "circle" set label "Platform 1"]
  create-platforms 1 [setxy 18 -7  set color green set shape "circle" set label "Platform 2"]
  create-platforms 1 [setxy 9 -2   set color green set shape "circle" set label "Platform 3"]
end

to setup-drones
  create-drones 3 [
    setxy 0 0
    set color red
    set mypacket            nobody
    set status              "ready"
    set charge              MaxCharge
    set label               who  
    set transportedpackets (list)
  ]
end

to setup-packets
  create-packets 10 [
    setxy 10 10
    set color yellow
    set shape "circle"
    set size .5
    set destination         platform 1
    set waitingtime         0
    set pickups             0
    set mydrone             nobody
  ]
  create-packets 4 [
    setxy -10 -10
    set color yellow
    set shape "circle"
    set size .5
    set destination         platform 3
    set waitingtime         0
    set pickups             0
    set mydrone             nobody
  ]
    create-packets 10 [
    setxy 9 -2
    set color yellow
    set shape "circle"
    set size .5
    set destination         platform 1
    set waitingtime         0
    set pickups             0
    set mydrone             nobody
  ]
      create-packets 10 [
    setxy -2 -10
    set color yellow
    set shape "circle"
    set size .5
    set destination         platform 0
    set waitingtime         0
    set pickups             0
    set mydrone             nobody
  ]
end

to go
  ask drones    with [status = "flying"     ]                 [fly          ]
  ask drones    with [status = "charging"   ]                 [recharge     ]
  ask drones    with [status = "ready"      ]                 [pickup       ]
  ask packets   with [mydrone = nobody      ]                 [countwaitingtime  ]
  ask drones    with [status = "waiting for new packets"]     [packetstopickup   ]
end

to fly
  set charge charge - consumption
  ;print (word "Drone " who "has this much charge left: " charge)
  if charge < 0 [if capacity != 0 [ask packets with [mydrone = dronewithpackets] [die] die]]
  ifelse mypacket      = nobody  [fly-empty] [fly-loaded]
end

to fly-loaded
  ask packets with [mydrone = dronewithpackets] 
  [print (word "Thanks drone" dronewithpackets " for dropping me, packet number " who " of at platform " position max destinationlist destinationlist) die]
  move-to dropoff
  if distance dropoff = 0
  [land]
end


to fly-empty
  ifelse any? packets with [mydrone = nobody]
    [set target one-of packets with [mydrone = nobody]
      move-to target
     if distance target = 0 
      [pickup]]
  [set status "waiting for new packets"
   print "No more packets to transport at the moment"]
end

to land
    set delivered delivered + capacity
  set status "charging"
end

to pickup
  ifelse any? packets-here with [mydrone = nobody]
    [ set destinationlist (list)
      set destinationlist lput (count packets-here with [destination = platform 0 and mydrone = nobody])  destinationlist
      set destinationlist lput (count packets-here with [destination = platform 1 and mydrone = nobody])  destinationlist
      set destinationlist lput (count packets-here with [destination = platform 2 and mydrone = nobody])  destinationlist
      set destinationlist lput (count packets-here with [destination = platform 3 and mydrone = nobody])  destinationlist
      ;print destinationlist 
      ;print (word "Platform " position max destinationlist destinationlist "is my next destination")
      ifelse max destinationlist >= 5 [set capacity 4][set capacity max destinationlist]
      set dronewithpackets who
      ask n-of capacity packets-here with [destination = platform (position max destinationlist destinationlist) and mydrone = nobody] [
        set mydrone dronewithpackets
        print (word "I am packet " who "and I am transported by drone " mydrone "to platform " position max destinationlist destinationlist)
        ;print (word "I have been waiting to be pickedup for " waitingtime )
  ]
      set dropoff platform (position max destinationlist destinationlist)
      set mypacket capacity
      set consumption capacity
      set pickedup pickedup + capacity
      ;print (word "I picked up " capacity " packet(s)")
      set transportedpackets lput capacity  transportedpackets
      ;print (word "I am drone " who " and I have transported " sum transportedpackets " packets today" )
      set status "flying"
      ]
   [set mypacket nobody              set consumption 1]
  set status "flying"
end

to recharge
  set charge charge + RechargePower
  if  charge > MaxCharge [set status "ready" ]
end

to countwaitingtime
  set waitingtime waitingtime + 1
end

to packetstopickup
  ifelse any? packets with [mydrone = nobody]
    [pickup] [fly-empty]
end
```

Comment: In the procedures `fly-loaded` and `fly-empty`, you have the command `move-to dropoff` and `move-to target`. This lines will  immediately move your agent to the destination, therefore you see the "jump" of your drone. Remove these lines and replace it with something like `while [ patch-here != target ] [fd 1 wait 0.2 face target]`. Your drone should face the destination now and move slowly towards it. Only a comment, not a solution since I did not test it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried using this, but if I use the while loop, the program does want to setup, but after making a single step, it gets jammed (you see an hour glass and the program doesn't responed anymore, so I have to restart it). Instead of "patch-here" I also tried to use "distance target != 0", as I figured it might be that it got jammed due to the fact that a target is not a patch, but this didin't solve the problem either. Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Replace all your `move-to` with something like:

```
face dropoff
forward 1
```

The `face` tells the turtle to change heading to go in the direction towards where it is trying to get to. This will move it forwards one unit distance each iteration through the go procedure.

You should consider adding time to your model by adding `tick` at the end of the `go` procedure, which advances the internal counter. You use time implicitly by, for example, increasing the waitingtime counter, but you don't actually have time progressing.

Once you have both `tick` and `forward` then the turtles will move 1 unit each tick and everything that happens simultaneously can occur during one tick. If you have a `go` button, that button instructs the model to run the `go` procedure once and you can edit the button to check 'forever' so that it keeps on calling the `go` procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using this, but it does not solve the problem, as the turtle only moves forward once in the right direction and thereafter it changes its direction again. What might be interesting is, that if I run the simulation forever, they all tend to move to Platform 3, but keep moving in random movements near it, without actually going there. I have now something like this for fly-loaded and fly-empty:
    [to fly-loaded
      face dropoff
      forward 1
      if distance dropoff = 0 [land]
    end]

Comment: You tell it to move forward 1 unit distance. Imagine it is 0.6 distance to the target, moving forward 1 will make it go past. You need to check distance to target and tell it to `move` to the target if distance < 1. To answer your question about moving to the wrong place and constantly changing direction, this suggests that you aren't setting the target the way you intend. Try opening an `inspect` window for one of the turtles that is moving in different directions and see where it things it is going.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do it. The `ifelse` statement in the `while` loop incorporates JenB comment, that the target is never reached with a step size of one, while the distance is lower than one.

Please check the `ifelse` below: if the distance is lower than one, the drone moves to the target. In case the distance is greater, it moves a step towards the target, waits 0.1 seconds (to show discrete steps) and the `while` loop is executed again until the drone reaches the target.

```
breed [targets target]
breed [drones drons]

to setup
  ca

  create-targets 5 [
    set shape "circle"
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

  ]

  create-drones 1 [
    set color red
  ]

end 

to go

ask one-of drones [

    ;; assuming you have multiple targets to choose from
    ;; if there is just one target, remove the line below
    let temp-target one-of targets 

    face temp-target

    while [distance temp-target != 0] [
      ifelse distance temp-target < 1 
      [ move-to temp-target ]
      [ wait 0.1 fd 1 ]
    ]
    show "target reached"
  ]

end
```